# Laravel - DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch - PhpWord error

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-5, phpword

I have 3 Blade files that are written in HTML, I am currently using WKHTMLTOPDF to export them to a PDF format, I now want to export the same HTML files to a Word Document.

So far, the best package for Laravel I can find is [PhpWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

Snippet of code:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>

<h3>Introduction</h3>

<p></p>

<p></p>
```

My code so far:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();    
$report = view('reports.audit-report', $data)->render();

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $report, true);

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

It is currently returning this error:

> DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1
>   and div in Entity, line: 1

The annoying thing is, is that no matter what line(s) I remove, that error always persists, until I remove literally every line of HTML!

I can prevent this error from happening by using the following code:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

However then, it returns:

> ErrorException in Html.php line 136: Trying to get property of non-object

Has anybody successfully resolved these errors before? If you require any more code, please just let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could the issue be no container tag? i.e. an <html>

Comment: My HTML file doesn't have the <html> tags, however, I have just added them and the same error is returned.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I have fixed it as coded below.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);
$doc->saveHTML();
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $doc->saveHtml(),true);
```

Comment: I have replaced `$doc->saveHtml()` by `$doc->saveXml()`.

Comment: it helps only if you have no custom tags inside

Answer (score 1):

The method `addHtml()` loads the provided string as XML. That means it needs to be valid XML, too. In other words you will have to use XHTML.

The error message says that you have a `link` tag in line 1. `link` is an empty element in (X)HTML. Saved as HTML it will look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div>Some Content</div>
```

This is not valid XML for 2 reasons. Here is no root element, but this is added by the `addHtml()` and the `link` element is not closed, triggering the error.

A valid XHTML fragment looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
<div>Some Content</div>
```

Or this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<div>Some Content</div>
```

In XML and empty tag can be written as `<link></link>` or `<link/>`. The `/` before the `>` closed the opening tag directly. Just the opening tag is invalid in XML/XHTML but valid in HTML.

So you need to make sure that your Blade files are valid XHTML fragments.

Comment: me getting an erro attributes construct error in Entity, line: 1

Comment: can anyone help